# jQuery: add class to parent element when child has class

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to add class '.open' to the parent li for the children with class .showme
I've tried several things so far (prev, prevAll, has etc) but I can't get it right.

This is my html structure and also a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jBz5/5) to work on. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
<ul class="product-categories">
    <li class="sub">
        <a href="#">Women</a>
        <ul>
            <li class=""> <a href="#">Clothing</a></li>
            <li class="showme"> <a href="#">Footwear</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="no-sub"> <a href="#">Men</a></li>
    <li class="no-sub"> <a href="#">Children</a></li>
    <li class="offers"> <a href="#">Offers</a></li>
</ul>

$(".showme").prevAll("li.sub:first").addClass("open")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .closest(), Find the first element with class .showme then find the closest parent li with class sub

```
$('.showme:first').closest('li.sub').addClass('open');
```

Comment: +1 to this for also including :first so that the search stops at first element found instead of searching the entire DOM.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".showme").closest("li.sub:first").addClass("open");
```

see reference **[closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)**

Comment: `:first` is superfluous since `.closest()` already selects only the first matching element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead of `prev()` as prev and `prevAll()` will look the previous siblings and you need to search the parent. You probably do not need :first in selector as cloest will return you **single** element.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7jBz5/4/)**

```
$(".showme").closest("li.sub").addClass("open")
```

As an additional note, you did not include required js `library` on given fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$('.showme').closest('li.sub').addClass('open');
```